# C# created files only appear after the program stops

Tags: c#, file

I have a program which will generate a log file every 10 minutes. That program will execute for around 2 months non-stop.

During testing, I found out that the files that were created only appears in the directory after the program was stopped. For example, if i start the program now and stop the execution 50 minutes later, i did not get to see the files in the directory every 10 minutes but i will see all 5 appear at once after i stopped the program.

is there a way to solve this? i would like to see the file every 10 minutes.

the file generation code:

```
timeDiff = now.Subtract(previous);
if (timeDiff.Minutes >= 10)
{
     StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path + "\\file" + i +".txt");
     sw.WriteLine("what ever text");
     sw.Close();
     i++;
}
```

Many thanks! and pardon for my English. (:

Comment: Curious - have you tried it with a `using` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the autoflush property
Quoting From MSDN

```
// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the StreamWriter 
// will flush its buffer to the underlying stream after every  
// call to StreamWriter.Write.
sw.AutoFlush = true;
```

Comment: While AutoFlush works it really is a bad habit since it will force a lot of disk writing if you are making a lot of calls `sw.Write()`/`sw.WriteLine`. It's better to manually call `sw.Flush()` before closing it (or at other appropriate times) to minimize this. It won't mater much in this specific case, but it's not a good habit to get in to.

Comment: Thanks Karl for the tip. i found out that either sw.AutoFlush() or sw.Flush() actually still produced the initial problem that i faced at times.

Does anyone know what happens when the flush method is called? it doesn't seem fast enough to write the file to disk.